# The introduction of a certain css property causes other unrelated properties to be ignored

Tags: html, css

I'm still trying to learn the ropes of css and I encountered a weird issue, never used SO before, so sorry if something is done the wrong way here

I'm trying to create a basic pure css3 interactive menu that displays drop down unordered lists on hover of the parent elements. It has 3 "depth levels", the "zeroth" level (which entails the item you can see on plain sight), the "first depth level" (which entails the first drop down menu with the names of languages), and the "second depth level" (which entails the list of items that appear when you hover over the word javascript on the "first depth level" drop-down menu)

The problem is that the first drop down menu ("first depth") appears slightly misaligned horizontally with respect to the "zeroth depth" element that shows the word "Frameworks and languages" (this is shown if you run the **first code snippet**), however to try and fix that, I added the property "margin-left:-0.05rem;" to the first css block of the section labeled "problem segment" in the css code, but when I do that, for some reason it causes the top and left margins specified on the second block of the "problem segment" of said css to be completely ignored, causing the 2nd drop down menu to display at a position I don't want it to (this is shown if you run the **second code snippet**)

Any idea as to what's causing the margins specified on that second block to be ignored? I tried this on different browsers and it works the same, even in the SO code snippet, I don't know what I'm missing here, afaik, margins are not inherited, but even if they were, the second block of the problem segment should overwrite anything specified on the first block

Any unrelated criticism of the code or suggestions are welcome as well..

**FIRST CODE SNIPPET**

```css
nav{
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#449944;
}
ul{
  padding:0%;
  list-style-type:none;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  width:15rem;
}
li{
  background-color:#BBBBBB;
  border:0.5px solid #AAAAAA;
  width:15rem;
  height:1.5rem;
  line-height:1.5rem;
}
ul ul{
  display:none;
}



/*Problem segment*/
li:hover>ul{
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left:-0.05rem;
}

ul.second_depth{
  margin-top:-1.55rem;
  margin-left:15rem;
  background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul class="zeroth_depth">
        <li>Frameworks and Languages
          <br>
          <ul class="first_depth">
              <li>Ruby</li>
              <li>Javascript
                 <br>
                 <ul class="second_depth">
                    <li>vue</li>
                    <li>react</li>
                    <li>angular</li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
              <li>Python</li>
          </ul>  
        </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

**SECOND CODE SNIPPET**

```css
nav{
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#449944;
}
ul{
  padding:0%;
  list-style-type:none;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  width:15rem;
}
li{
  background-color:#BBBBBB;
  border:0.5px solid #AAAAAA;
  width:15rem;
  height:1.5rem;
  line-height:1.5rem;
}
ul ul{
  display:none;
}



/*Problem segment*/
li:hover>ul{
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left:-0.05rem;
}

ul.second_depth{
  margin-top:-1.55rem;
  margin-left:15rem;
  background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul class="zeroth_depth">
        <li>Frameworks and Languages
          <br>
          <ul class="first_depth">
              <li>Ruby</li>
              <li>Javascript
                 <br>
                 <ul class="second_depth">
                    <li>vue</li>
                    <li>react</li>
                    <li>angular</li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
              <li>Python</li>
          </ul>  
        </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The margins are ignored because you have `position: absolute`. Once you do that, the element is taken out of the flow, and margins (the offset from a container) become somewhat meaningless.

To position the menu, use `left` and `top` rather than `margin-left` and `margin-top`.

```css
nav{
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#449944;
}
ul{
  padding:0%;
  list-style-type:none;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  width:15rem;
}
li{
  background-color:#BBBBBB;
  border:0.5px solid #AAAAAA;
  width:15rem;
  height:1.5rem;
  line-height:1.5rem;
}
ul ul{
  display:none;
}



/*Problem segment*/
li:hover>ul{
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left:-0.05rem;
}

ul.second_depth{
  top:1.55rem;
  left:15rem;
  background-color:white; /* since the `li` elements have backgrounds, you'll never see this */
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul class="zeroth_depth">
        <li>Frameworks and Languages
          <br>
          <ul class="first_depth">
              <li>Ruby</li>
              <li>Javascript
                 <br>
                 <ul class="second_depth">
                    <li>vue</li>
                    <li>react</li>
                    <li>angular</li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
              <li>Python</li>
          </ul>  
        </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Note that I inverted the value of `top` since I assumed you wanted the menu appearing to the right of the menu item it was a child of.

Note also that `background-color:white` won't be visible, since the child `li` elements have a different `background-color` already set.

Comment: Oh, hmm I see, I thought they could work since they seemed fine until I added the other margin, thanks for pointing that out. You left the "margin-left" on the first block of the "problem segment", was it intentional? as for the "background-color", whoops haha, I had intended to remove that but forgot, thanks for pointing it out as well